# CodeIgniter get a URL variable from method position?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using code igniter and my URL structure looks like this:

`http://localhost:8888/project/register`

Register in this case is the controller.

I am trying to pass an ID to this URL, something like so:

`http://localhost:8888/project/register/1234` so that I can use this value in my controller.

I am running into an issue trying to figure that out since the position of this ID is meant for the name of a method within the controller.

Is it possible to add a value in this position without it thinking its a method or do I need to do something like : 
`http://localhost:8888/project/register?code=1234` ?

Trying to access it like so: `$registerPin = $this->common->nohtml($this->uri->segment(2));`

**Update:**

As a hack workaround, I did this.. Any better ways?

URL: http://localhost:8888/project/register/c/1234

```
/**
 * Pass our signup code for demo purposes
 */
public function c(){

    // Did we come here from a Sign-up Pin?
    $registerPin = $this->common->nohtml($this->uri->segment(3));

    if($registerPin){
        $this->session->set_userdata(array(
            'registerPin'  => $registerPin
        ));
    }

    // Redirect to register
    redirect(site_url("register"));

}

public function index()
{   
 echo $this->session->userdata('registerPin');
}
```

Comment: if i understand correctly, you can route `register/\d+` to `register/index/$1`

Comment: @BrianGottier I could care less about reputation on this site, I learn by asking questions that I have not figured out myself after trying :)

Comment: Why don't you pass an argument (i.e. `public function c($id = false){` here, false default is just example option)?

Comment: i dont even understand the purpose of this...

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use the Controller's _remap functionality, although I've not used this the way you're intending to use it. (Hopefully it works)

See: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#remapping-method-calls

```
<?php 

class Register extends MY_Controller{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Controller remapping
     */
    public function _remap( $method, $params = [] )
    {
        if( is_numeric( $method ) )
        {
            $this->index( $method );
        }
        else
        {
            $this->$method();
        }
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Index method
     */
    public function index( $num )
    {
        # code...
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Another solution would be to use URI routing.

See: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

```
$route['register/(:num)'] = 'register/index/$1';
```

Neither of these examples may be fully functional in your case, but should be close to what you need.